# Upload image with socketio-file-upload

Tags: node.js, sockets, file-upload, socket.io, pug

I'm trying to upload files with socketio-file-upload, so far it does the job quite well, selecting the "upload image" button correctly uploads the file to the folder of my preference. My problem is that any button that clicks "Search for file" or "ClickHere" uploads the file without giving me the name of the file you select. What I want to achieve is

- 1.- Press the "Upload Image" button
- 2.- Show file name
- 3.- Upload the file to the selected folder by clicking the button "ClickHere"
  Here is the code I am using

main.js

```
//Connection to the socket library
const socket = io();

//This is some classic socket.io event listening
socket.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data);
});
//Here is our socketio-file-upload code
const uploader = new SocketIOFileUpload(socket);

//uploader.listenOnInput(document.getElementById('fileUpload'));
uploader.listenOnInput(document.getElementById('fileUpload'));


uploader.addEventListener('start', (event)=> {
    event.file.meta.extension = 'csv';
});

document.getElementById('file_button').addEventListener('click', uploader.prompt, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Socket.IO File Upload documentation](https://github.com/vote539/socketio-file-upload#instancelistenonsubmitsubmitbutton-input):

> **instance.listenOnSubmit(submitButton, input)**
>
> Like `instance.listenOnInput(input)`, except instead of listening for the "change" event on the input element, listen for the "click" event of a button.
>
> JavaScript:
>
> ```
> instance.listenOnSubmit(document.getElementById("my_button"), document.getElementById("file_input"));
> ```
>
> HTML:
>
> ```
> <label>Upload File: <input type="file" id="file_input" /></label>
> <button id="my_button">Upload File</button>
> ```

Try something like this:

main.js

```
//Connection to the socket library
const socket = io();

//This is some classic socket.io event listening
socket.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data);
});
//Here is our socketio-file-upload code
const uploader = new SocketIOFileUpload(socket);

// When #file_button is clicked, the file in #fileUpload is uploaded.
uploader.listenOnSubmit(document.getElementById('file_button'), document.getElementById('fileUpload'));

uploader.addEventListener('start', (event)=> {
    event.file.meta.extension = 'csv';
});
```

Comment: It seems to insert correctly, but in console I get this:
Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'files' of null at Object.listenOnSubmit (client.js: 12) at main.js: 12
It is this line:
uploader.listenOnSubmit (document.getElementById ('file_button'), document.getElementById ('fileUpload'));

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why. It looks like the issue is that it's saying the #fileUpload input doesn't exist, but it does.